# remove first comma of one column with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If i have a dataframe as following:

```
id         fruits
01     ,Apple, Apricot
02     ,Apple, Banana, Clementine, Pear
03     ,Orange, Pineapple, Pear
```

How can remove first comma and get a new dataframe like this:

```
id      fruits
01     Apple, Apricot
02     Apple, Banana, Clementine, Pear
03     Orange, Pineapple, Pear
```

Comment: Is always first value `,` ? If yes, then it is dupe.

Comment: yes.. sorry i didn't find another link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html):

```
df['fruits'] = df['fruits'].str.lstrip(',')
print (df)
   id                           fruits
0   1                   Apple, Apricot
1   2  Apple, Banana, Clementine, Pear
2   3          Orange, Pineapple, Pear
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['fruits'] = df['fruits'].str[1:]
```